# I have been tagged in a photo on google plus

Tags: google-plus-photos

I deleted the post from my phone, but did deleting it take my name off of it? Or does the person who tagged me still have it?  I'd like to know if, on my settings, I can stop anyone from tagging.  Or is that possible?

I went on Chrome and logged into Google. When I went to my previously read notifications, I clicked on the one saying I had been tagged. I pressed the icon at the top right corner and "delete" was one of the options. When I pressed "delete" it asked if I was sure I wanted to delete this post, and I clicked "yes"

Comment: How did you delete someone else's post? Did you mean something else?

Comment: Please go to the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page to merge your two accounts.  That way you will retain the editing privileges on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did, but unless you removed the tag from the photo you're still tagged.